# AADB2C: The request URI ' ' resolves to an IP address which is in a restricted IP range

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

No matter which externally hosted Rest Api endpoint do I pass to the custom policy xml, AADB2C raises this error for all the URIs

Trying to create a custom policy to connect with one of the locally hosted restful api endpoints (with user journey as an orchestration step)

I expect to hit the locally hosted Restful endpoint- 'GetListOfDepartments', but the actual output is AADB2C: The request URI 'http://localhost:5000/api/businesslogic/GetListOfDepartments' resolves to an IP address which is in a restricted IP range

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a REST claims provider, `localhost` represents the Azure AD B2C host, not your own localhost.

If you're wanting to invoke a locally-hosted endpoint (i.e. one that's hosted on your own localhost), then you must proxy through a secure tunnel such as [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/).

Comment: Yeah, custom UI can be loaded from localhost since that is loaded via AJAX in the browser. These API requests occur in the back-end so... Yeah you can't use localhost for them, it needs to be publicly accessible.